# How to fix my multiple account sign-in issues?

Tags: accounts

I have multiple accounts active on my phone. I started by using my custom domain Google account, because it had my contacts. When I got on Google+, I couldn't use that account, so I had to link my normal Gmail account with my phone. And when I added my YouTube account, it threw that account on there too.

Now, in intervals that range from every few days to every few minutes, i get a notification 
that says **"Sign In error with account (account name here)"**, then asks me to enter a capcha-like entry (enter letters of distorted words).

It usually happens to the standard Google account (@gmail.com), but has happened with all three at one time or another. Anyone know why this would be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this forum](http://androidforums.com/htc-droid-eris/79426-sign-error-issue.html) deleting the YouTube account resolves it.

Comment: what if i want to upload videos to youtube? would i have to sign in every time and sign out when i'm done?

Comment: Guess so. I've don't really upload to YouTube so I'm not really sure.